# Assigning multiple attributes to nodes

Tags: python, networkx

I would like to assign to my nodes an attribute. Currently I am creating a network using the following sample of data:

```
Attribute   Source       Target Weight  Label
    87.5    Heisenberg   Pauli  66.3    1
    12.5    Beckham      Messi  38.1    0
    12.5    Beckham      Maradona 12    0
    43.5    water        melon  33.6    1
```

Label should give the colour of nodes (1=yellow, 0=blue).

Code for network:

```
 G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='Source', target='Target', edge_attr='Weight') 

    collist = df.drop('Weight', axis=1).melt('Label').dropna() # I need this for the below lines of code because I want to draw nodes - their size - based on their degree

    degrees=[]
    for x in collist['value']:
        deg=G.degree[x]  
        degrees.append(100*deg)

    
    pos=nx.spring_layout(G)

    nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, font_size=10)
    nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, nodelist=collist['value'], node_size = degrees, node_color=collist['Label'])
    nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos)
```

What this code is supposed to do is the following: the nodes should have size equal their degree (this explains degrees and `collist` in my code). Edges should have thickness equal to `Weight`. `Attribute` should be assigned (and updated) as in this link: ([Changing attributes of nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67272242/changing-attributes-of-nodes)). Currently, my code does not include the assignment as in the link mentioned, where it was added and updated as follows:

```
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_node(0, weight=8)
G.add_node(1, weight=5)
G.add_node(2, weight=3)
G.add_node(3, weight=2)

nx.add_path(G, [2,5])
nx.add_path(G, [2,3])


labels = {
    n: str(n) + '\nweight=' + str(G.nodes[n]['weight']) if 'weight' in G.nodes[n] else str(n)
    for n in G.nodes
}

newWeights = \
    [
        sum( # summ for averaging
            [G.nodes[neighbor]['weight'] for neighbor in G.neighbors(node)] # weight of every neighbor
            + [G.nodes[i]['weight']] # adds the node itsself to the average
        ) / (len(list(G.neighbors(node)))+1) # average over number of neighbours+1
        if len(list(G.neighbors(node))) > 0 # if there are no neighbours
        else G.nodes[i]['weight'] # weight stays the same if no neighbours
    for i,node in enumerate(G.nodes) # do the above for every node
    ]
print(newWeights) 
for i, node in enumerate(G.nodes):
    G.nodes[i]['weight'] = newWeights[i] # writes new weights after it calculated them all.
```

Please note that I have more than 100 nodes so I cannot do it manually.
I tried to include the Attribute in my code as follows:

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df_net, source='Source', target='Target', edge_attr=['Weight'])
    nx.set_node_attributes(G, pd.Series(nodes.Attribute, index=nodes.node).to_dict(), 'Attribute')
```

However, I have got the error:

```
----> 1 network(df)

<ipython-input-72-f68985d20046> in network(dataset)
     24     degrees=[]
     25     for x in collist['value']:
---> 26         deg=G.degree[x]
     27         degrees.append(100*deg)
     28 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/networkx/classes/reportviews.py in __getitem__(self, n)
    445     def __getitem__(self, n):
    446         weight = self._weight
--> 447         nbrs = self._succ[n]
    448         if weight is None:
    449             return len(nbrs) + (n in nbrs)

KeyError: 87.5
```

What I would like to have as expected output is a network where nodes are in the Source column and their neighbors are within the Target column. Edges have thickness based on Weight. Label gives the colour of the source, while Attribute value should be added as label and updated as in the question/answer on this link: [Changing attributes of nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67272242/changing-attributes-of-nodes) .

Please see below a visual example of the type of net that I am trying to build. The attribute value in the figure is meant before the update (newWeights), and this explains why some nodes have missing value.   Attribute is related to Source only, which is colored based on Label. The thickness of the edge is given by Weight.

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of [Adding Attributes to Nodes from Dataframe in a Network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48370543/adding-attributes-to-nodes-from-dataframe-in-a-network?noredirect=1&lq=1) with answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42558578/11339311)

Comment: Please follow the accepted answer, i.e.,  https://stackoverflow.com/a/42558578/11339311, and not the other (not helping answer) from the Adding Attributes question.

Comment: I updated the question, including what I changed after following the accepted answer in the link you mentioned. I think I am still missing or doing wrong something

Comment: Can you add for your minimal example data frame, the desired `networkx` graph. So which edge/node attributes should be created (before applying this average calculation, where you already have a solution for). Because currently it is confusing, should Beckham have attribute 12.5 or 23.5? Is weight only the note attribute of target or source - or the edge? I'm also unclear what you now mean with "width", if you expect to create a figure, where each edge have exactly the length of a given attribute, then that's sadly not (easily/automatically) possible.

Comment: I spot two errors in the dataframe that now I fixed. Thank you so much @Sparky05. I included an example of network that I am trying to build. `Attribute=` is what I would need to calculate based on `newWeights`. It could be outside or inside the node (without `Attribute=`). On the width, I meant thickness. Beckham should have attribute 12.5 and not 23.5 (fixed). Thank you so much, also for spotting those typos while I was reporting the example.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections, before it was confusing. I hope my answer now solves all your issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({"Attribute": [87.5, 12.5, 12.5, 43.5], "Source": ["Heisenberg", "Beckham", "Messi", "water"], "Target" : ["Pauli", "Messi", "Maradona", "melon"], "Weight" : [66.3, 38.1, 12, 33.6], "Label" : [1, 0, 0,1]})

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='Source', target='Target', edge_attr='Weight')

source_attrs = {df.Source[i]: {"Attribute": df.Attribute[i]} for i in range(len(df.Attribute))}

target_attrs = {df.Target[i]: {"Attribute": df.Attribute[i]} for i in range(len(df.Attribute))}



nx.set_node_attributes(G, source_attrs)
nx.set_node_attributes(G, target_attrs)

degrees=[100*G.degree[i] for i in G.nodes()]
weights = [G[u][v]['Weight']/10 for u,v in G.edges()]
colors = []
for node in G.nodes():
    if node in source_attrs.keys():
        colors.append('yellow')
    else:
        colors.append('blue')

pos=nx.spring_layout(G)

pos_attrs = {}
for node, coords in pos.items():
    pos_attrs[node] = (coords[0], coords[1] + 0.08)

labels = nx.get_node_attributes(G, "Attribute")

custom_node_attrs = {}
for node, attr in labels.items():
    custom_node_attrs[node] = str(node) + str(attr)

nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos_attrs, labels=custom_node_attrs, font_size=10)

nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, nodelist=G.nodes(), node_size = degrees, node_color=colors)

nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos, width=weights)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From your given example data frame and the desired output image, I created the following solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pylab as pl

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[[87.5, "Heisenberg", "Pauli", 66.3, 1, ],
          [12.5, "Beckham", "Messi", 38.1, 0, ],
          [12.5, "Beckham", "Maradona", 12, 0, ],
          [43.5, "water", "melon", 33.6, 1, ]],
    columns=["Attribute", "Source", "Target", "Weight", "Label"]
)

# 1 Creating the graph
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='Source', target='Target', edge_attr='Weight')

# 2 Adding the node attributes for the source nodes
nx.set_node_attributes(G, {node: df.Attribute[i] for i, node in enumerate(df.Source)}, 'Attribute')
nx.set_node_attributes(G, {node: df.Label[i] for i, node in enumerate(df.Source)}, 'Label')

# (optional) checking the created data 
print(G.nodes(data=True))
# [('Heisenberg', {'Attribute': 87.5, 'Label': 1}), ('Pauli', {}), ('Beckham', {'Attribute': 12.5, 'Label': 0}), ('Messi', {}), ('Maradona', {}), ('water', {'Attribute': 43.5, 'Label': 1}), ('melon', {})]
print(G.edges(data=True))
# [('Heisenberg', 'Pauli', {'Weight': 66.3}), ('Beckham', 'Messi', {'Weight': 38.1}), ('Beckham', 'Maradona', {'Weight': 12.0}), ('water', 'melon', {'Weight': 33.6})]

# 3 fine tuning the visualisation 
degrees = [100 * G.degree[i] for i in G.nodes()]
# not sure what should be the color if no label is available
color_dict = {0: "blue", 1: "yellow", "default": "yellow"}
node_colors = []
labels = {}
for node in G:
    label = node + "\n Attribute="
    if "Attribute" in G.nodes[node]:
        label += str(G.nodes[node]["Attribute"])
    labels[node] = label

    if "Label" in G.nodes[node]:
        node_colors.append(color_dict[G.nodes[node]["Label"]])
    else:
        node_colors.append(color_dict["default"])

# you can use any other layout e.g spring_layout
pos = nx.circular_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx(G,
                 pos,
                 node_color=node_colors,
                 node_size=degrees,
                 width=[edge_info[2]/10 for edge_info in G.edges(data="Weight")],
                 labels=labels,
                 )

# 4 Adjustments for node labels partially cut
axis = pl.gca()
# zoom out
# maybe smaller factors work as well, but 1.3 works fine for this minimal example
axis.set_xlim([1.3*x for x in axis.get_xlim()])
axis.set_ylim([1.3*y for y in axis.get_ylim()])
# turn off frame
pl.axis("off")
pl.show()
```

With the following result

[image: Output Figure]

#### Explanation

The main step for creating the network are the following:

1. The easiest part is the creation of the basic network with `nx.from_pandas_edgelist`, which already added edge weights.
2. Afterwards, adding the node attributes using `nx.set_node_attributes`.
3. Then, the graph is completely created and all following code should only operate on the graph, e.g. `G.nodes()`. Hence, for adjusting the visualisation only loops over `G`.
4. Finally, I fine tuned the created matplotlib figure to avoid cutting of the labels.

Answer (score 0):

`edge_attr` argument of [from_pandas_edgelist()](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_edgelist.html) can accept a list

```py
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='Source', target='Target', edge_attr=['Weight', 'Attribute'])
```

What's the purpose of your `melt`? If you want to see label of each node, you can use

```py
df['Node'] = df['Source'].str.cat(df['Target'], sep=' ').str.split(' ')
df = df.explode('Node')
```

```
print(df)

   Attribute      Source    Target  Weight  Label        Node
0       87.5  Heisenberg     Pauli    66.3      1  Heisenberg
0       87.5  Heisenberg     Pauli    66.3      1       Pauli
1       12.5     Beckham     Messi    38.1      1     Beckham
1       12.5     Beckham     Messi    38.1      1       Messi
2       23.5     Beckham  Maradona    12.0      0     Beckham
2       23.5     Beckham  Maradona    12.0      0    Maradona
3       43.5       water     melon    33.6      1       water
3       43.5       water     melon    33.6      1       melon
```

But there are duplicate nodes having different label, you need to choose which to keep.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Ynjxsjmh. I had tried with your proposed answer, but I have got the same error (87.5)  because of `---> 26         deg=G.degree[x]`. This part of code needs for sizing the nodes based on their degree. Did you try to create the network? I was wondering if you got the same error

Comment: @Val Why do you use `melt`?

Comment: `melt` creates the value that I use for the degree (to assign each nodes a degree, then a size). Unfortunately I have not found another way to let my code works alternatively, i.e. assigning nodes a size equal their degree, edges with width equal to Weight, and a color based on the label

Comment: @Val I didn't see anything related with `degree` in your dataframe. In my answer, I use `explode` to create a dataframe, is that what you want?

Comment: the degree is used in this piece of code (in my question): `node_size = degrees, node_color=collist['Label']` . It is not about exploding, but in using the degree to size nodes.

Comment: @Val `KeyError: 87.5` is very obvious. If you print `collist` created from `melt`. You will notice that `value` column contains some numeric number. Then you use `nodelist=collist['value']`, however, you have never created those numeric number as node before.

Comment: @Val That's the reason why I question the purpose of your `melt`.

Comment: how should I replace it? Unfortunately it is still not clear. I tried without melt but I got the same KeyError

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231731/discussion-between-ynjxsjmh-and-val).